# How to make a join with the same table to insert the maximum column value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that keeps activity records, containing the date of registration and other information about the activity performed. I would like to make a query that would return one more column in the table, containing the maximum record date.

I don't think it's too complicated, but my knowledge is limited on the subject. Would a join between tables be the solution? How can I do it?

my original table:

| ID | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 34 | 2022-02-15 |
| 01 | 42 | 2022-02-08 |
| 02 | 12 | 2022-02-08 |
| 02 | 30 | 2022-02-01 |

I need to get:

| ID | Value | Date | Date_max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 34 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-15 |
| 01 | 42 | 2022-02-08 | 2022-02-15 |
| 02 | 12 | 2022-02-08 | 2022-02-15 |
| 02 | 30 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-15 |

I just need a column with the global maximum value. It will be the same value for all rows.

Comment: Editing problem, adjusted Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
select id, value, date, max(date) over () as date_max
from the_table
order by id, date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: getting the max date with subquery:

```
select id, value, date, (select max(date) from original_table) Date_max
    from original_table o
    order by id
```

Comment: Max Date, not max date by ID.  Note all records indicate 2022-02-15 as "max"

Comment: Id wise max date is also '2022-02-15'. And for max date only an correct answer is already provided.

Comment: I disagree.  Wouldn't max(date) over (partition by ID) return a date of 2022-02-08 for ID 02 as it's the "MAX Date" within ID 02.  As to the other options.  They look good.

Comment: @xQbert thanks for your correction. I misunderstood the sample data. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this:

- Analytic function if it's available to you.
- Inline Select query
- cross join

.  The 1st two have been covered in answers already  so here's a 3rd option.  The analytic would be the most "modern" way to handle this I can think of.

```
SELECT A.*, B.Date_Max
FROM Table A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT max(Date) Date_Max FROM Table Sub) B
```